# Connect sibling vertices MATLAB

Tags: matlab, treeview

How do i connect sibling vertices? using matlab and function treeplot,
for example:connect vertex 2 and 3.

example of a connection:https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBLk3.png

How do i connect multiple parents?using matlab and function treeplot
for example :the parents of vertex 5 need be both vertices 2 and 6.
code:

```
 

 p(1)=0;
 p(2)=1;p(3)=1;
 p(6)=3;p(7)=3;
p(5)=2;p(4)=2;
p(10)=5;p(11)=5;
p(8)=4;p(9)=4;
p(16)=8;p(17)=9;
p(14)=7;p(15)=7;
p(20)=14;p(19)=14;
p(20)=15;p(19)=15;
%p.edgelable=0;
treeplot(p);
[x,y] = treelayout(p);
for i=1:length(y)
    text(x(i),y(i),strcat('a',num2str(i)))
end
 for i = 2: length(p)
    Parent_Node = p(i);
    if(Parent_Node > 0)
        X_Midpoint = (x(i) + x(Parent_Node))/2;
        Y_Midpoint = (y(i) + y(Parent_Node))/2;
        text(X_Midpoint,Y_Midpoint,'num of sharings')
    end
 end
'''
```

Comment: Do you want a strictly scalable and automatic solution or is manually doing a connection using the `line()` function sufficient?

Comment: how can i connect vertices using line function and also label the lines?

Comment: I’ve added an answer below. Please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

### Drawing Additional Lines Manually

The additional parents that need to be connected can be manually done by drawing additional lines. The `line()` function takes two arrays that specify the `x` and `y` coordinates of the lines start and end points. To find the corresponding locations of the nodes that need to be connected the array `p` can be indexed as `p(node_value)` where the `node_value` is the label on each node/dot.

```
p(1)=0;
p(2)=1;p(3)=1;
p(6)=3;p(7)=3;
p(5)=2;p(4)=2;
p(10)=5;p(11)=5;
p(8)=4;p(9)=4;
p(16)=8;p(17)=9;
p(14)=7;p(15)=7;
p(20)=14;p(19)=14;
p(20)=15;p(19)=15;

%p.edgelable=0;
treeplot(p);
[x,y] = treelayout(p);
for i=1:length(y)
text(x(i),y(i),strcat('a',num2str(i)))
end

for i = 2: length(p)
Parent_Node = p(i);
if(Parent_Node > 0)
    X_Midpoint = (x(i) + x(Parent_Node))/2;
    Y_Midpoint = (y(i) + y(Parent_Node))/2;
    text(X_Midpoint,Y_Midpoint,["num of";"sharings"],'FontSize',7);
end
end

line([x(2) x(3)],[y(2) y(3)],'color','r');
X_Midpoint = (x(2) + x(3))/2;
Y_Midpoint = (y(2) + y(3))/2;
text(X_Midpoint,Y_Midpoint,["num of";"sharings"],'FontSize',7);
line([x(6) x(7)],[y(6) y(7)],'color','r');
X_Midpoint = (x(6) + x(7))/2;
Y_Midpoint = (y(6) + y(7))/2;
text(X_Midpoint,Y_Midpoint,["num of";"sharings"],'FontSize',7);
```